# List out unimplemented python functions without running the application

Tags: python, static-analysis

Is there a way to produce a sensible, readable (or any other kind) list of unimplemented methods/classes using some form of static analysis? Can I skip the painful waiting for processing/network operations to finish for 15 minutes, just to see unimplemented errors one at a time?

Before starting with more serious design decisions, I like to lay out the skeleton of the core of the application. That usually means writing a bunch of imaginary functions that would be implemented eventually. This allows me to think in a conformist way, providing me with an API that's oriented towards easier usage. This is in contrast with the head-first approach of writing the API first with ease of implementation in mind.

While it appears sensible to write the API first, it actually tends to be riddled with bad design decisions. Implementing the core of the application with the idealistic imaginary API tends to provide a clearer idea of how should the API be implemented. Also the tendency is for the API to be less entangled itself.

There is one issue with this however. I usually go all shakespeare on it, so I oft forget what was I wanting to use in the first place. Solution? Run it, see where it cries out about non implemented stuff, implement it, rinse and repeat.
Now, once there's over 50% of the API implemented, rest of it is usually called only after some other heavy processing (which can take up quite a bit of the execution time), leaving me waiting for the not implemented errors. Oh and since python is interpreted, that's where it stops. So I can't really just take the first error log and implement stuff using it as a listing.

Comment: Define *unimplemented* here. Are your functions there but empty, for example?

Comment: As you already noticed, you should learn TDD. Apart from it, any good IDE should warn you about unimplemented methods/classes.

Comment: By *"writing a bunch of imaginary functions"* are you talking about `raise NotImplementedError`? It would be easy enough to parse a Python code file for those, I should think. As @Selcuk mentions, your IDE may already do this for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you note which parts did you edit? I feel like I should know at least. Unimplemented as in I didn't even think of writing those yet.
I generally do not use IDEs, prefer vim to those, any plugins you could suggest?

Comment: @Johnny if you click on *"edited ... ago"* it will show you. *"Unimplemented as in I didn't even think of writing those yet"* - you want to look for things that don't exist yet?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for that, haven't had a post of mine edited yet, nor was curious enough to look for other edits. Nope, I've *used* them, haven't defined them as empty.

Comment: @Johnny tools like [`pylint`](http://www.pylint.org/) will warn you that you're referring to names that don't exist, and will work with vim. It is more conventional to define an empty function/method that will `raise NotImplementedError`, though; then it's trivial to search your code for them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was put off of pylint due to most of these projects being rather small (I know, just as I should be doing TDD, I'm just looking for a quickfix here, don't hate on me, most people will probably appreciate this kind of a question). So yeah, that sounds like a thing that'd work, I'll just make a small pylint config that'll warn me only about notimplemented ones. I suggest you make that an answer while I go and see if that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74649/discussion-between-johnny-and-jonrsharpe).